# Python Beginner: Selective Printing in loops

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm a very new python user (had only a little prior experience with html/javascript as far as programming goes), and was trying to find some ways to output only intermittent numbers in my loop for a basic bicycle racing simulation (10,000 lines of biker positions would be pretty excessive :P).

I tried in this loop several 'reasonable' ways to communicate a condition where a floating point number equals its integer floor (int, floor division) to print out every 100 iterations or so:

```
 for i in range (0,10000):
  i = i + 1
  t = t + t_step #t is initialized at 0 while t_step is set at .01
  acceleration_rider1 = (power_rider1 / (70 * velocity_rider1)) - (force_drag1 / 70)
  velocity_rider1 = velocity_rider1 + (acceleration_rider1 * t_step)
  position_rider1 = position_rider1 + (velocity_rider1 * t_step)
  force_drag1 = area_rider1 * (velocity_rider1 ** 2) 
  acceleration_rider2 = (power_rider2 / (70 * velocity_rider1)) - (force_drag2 / 70)
  velocity_rider2 = velocity_rider2 + (acceleration_rider2 * t_step)
  position_rider2 = position_rider2 + (velocity_rider2 * t_step)
  force_drag2 = area_rider1 * (velocity_rider2 ** 2)

  if t == int(t): #TRIED t == t // 1 AND OTHER VARIANTS THAT DON'T WORK HERE:(
   print t, "biker 1", position_rider1, "m", "\t", "biker 2", position_rider2, "m"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can format your code by indenting it with four spaces, or let the button do it for you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The for loop auto increments for you, so you don't need to use `i = i + 1`.

You don't need `t`, just use `%` (modulo) operator to find multiples of a number.

```
# Log every 1000 lines.
LOG_EVERY_N = 1000

for i in range(1000):
  ... # calculations with i

  if (i % LOG_EVERY_N) == 0:
    print "logging: ..."
```

Answer (score 6):

To print out every 100 iterations, I'd suggest

```
if i % 100 == 0: ...
```

If you'd rather not print the very first time, then maybe

```
if i and i % 100 == 0: ...
```

(as another answer noted, the `i = i + 1` is supererogatory given that `i` is the control variable of the for loop anyway -- it's not particularly *damaging* though, just somewhat superfluous, and is not really relevant to the issue of why your `if` doesn't trigger).

While basing the condition on `t` may seem appealing, `t == int(t)` is unlikely to work unless the `t_step` is a multiple of `1.0 / 2**N` for some integer `N` -- fractions cannot be represented exactly in a float unless this condition holds, because floats use a binary base. (You *could* use `decimal.Decimal`, but that would seriously impact the speed of your computation, since `float` computation are directly supported by your machine's hardware, while decimal computations are not).

Comment: Yeah, I was using my own crude method to avoid printing out the first value of t... always great to learn a little more computing theory with each mistake made, though :)

Answer (score 3):

*The other answers suggest that you use the integer variable `i` instead. That also works, and is the solution I would recommend. This answer is mostly for educational value.*

I think it's a roundoff error that is biting you. Floating point numbers can often not be represented exactly, so adding `.01` to `t` for `100` times is not guaranteed to result in `t == 1`:

```
>>> sum([.01]*100)
1.0000000000000007
```

So when you compare to an actual integer number, you need to build in a small tolerance margin. Something like this should work:

```
if abs(t - int(t)) < 1e-6:
 print t, "biker 1", position_rider1, "m", "\t", "biker 2", position_rider2, "m"
```

Comment: hmm, that's really interesting, I never knew about this 'error margin' in simple operations before... I'll have to try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use python library called [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) (tqdm derives from the Arabic word taqaddum (تقدّم) which can mean "progress) for showing progress and use write() method from tqdm to print intermittent log statements as answered by @Stephen

**Why using tqdm is useful in your case?**

- Shows compact & fancy progress bar with very minimal code change.
- Does not fill your console with thousands of log statement and yet shows accurate iteration progress of your for loop.

**Caveats:**

- Can not use `logging` library as it writes output stdout only. Though you can [redirect it to logfile very easily](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/#redirecting-writing).
- Adds little performance overhead.

**Code**

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

# Log every 100 lines.
LOG_EVERY_N = 100

for i in tqdm(range(1,1000)):
    if i%LOG_EVERY_N == 0:
        tqdm.write(f"loggig : {i}")
        sleep(0.5)
```

**How to install ?**

```
pip install tqdm
```

**Sample GIF that shows console output**

[image]